# which application_rb file should I edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller

On my server I did a search with `sudo find . -name "application_controller.rb"`. There's so many files of that name. Which one should I edit so the changes will be reflected on my server?

```
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140208000704/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140116094931/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140114154804/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140117124202/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140120094758/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140116102758/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140117125636/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140116123905/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140116115403/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140117090645/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140121091622/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140212214841/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases/20140205001541/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/cached-copy/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/best_in_place-1.1.2/test_app/app/controllers/application_co      ntroller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/sass_project/app/controllers      /application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/engine_project/app/controlle      rs/engine_project/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/engine_project/test/dummy/ap      p/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/scss_project/app/controllers      /application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.6/test/rails_app/app/controllers/application_con      troller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-graph-2.0.1/example/rails3/app/controllers/application      _controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rest-graph-2.0.1/example/rails2/app/controllers/application      _controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/app      /controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/guides/code/getting_started/app/controllers/      application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/gmaps4rails-1.5.6/spec/dummy/app/controllers/application_co      ntroller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/best_in_place-1.1.2/test_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/email_spec-1.2.1/examples/rails3_root/app/controllers/application_contr      oller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/sass_project/app/controllers/application      _controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/engine_project/app/controllers/engine_pr      oject/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/engine_project/test/dummy/app/controller      s/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/test/fixtures/scss_project/app/controllers/application      _controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/devise-2.0.6/test/rails_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rest-graph-2.0.1/example/rails3/app/controllers/application_controller.      rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rest-graph-2.0.1/example/rails2/app/controllers/application_controller.      rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/app/controllers      /application_controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.3/guides/code/getting_started/app/controllers/application_      controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails3.0/app/controllers/application_control      ler.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails3.2/app/controllers/application_control      ler.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails2.3/app/controllers/application_control      ler.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails4.0/app/controllers/application_control      ler.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails3.1/app/controllers/application_control      ler.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails_apps/2.3/empty/app/controllers/applica      tion_controller.rb
./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails_apps/2.3/mycook/app/controllers/applic      ation_controller.rb
myapp@myapp:/$ sufo nano ./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails_apps/      2.3/mycook/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
-bash: sufo: command not found
myapp@myapp:/$ sudo nano ./home/myapp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.14/test/stub/rails_apps/      2.3/mycook/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
myapp@myapp:/$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change any of them. Really.

`./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases` suggests you are using something like Capistrano to deploy your application. You should update your source code, commit, and deploy it.

If that's not an option, then you should see if `./home/myapp/apps/myapp/current/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` exists and edit that. If not, pick the most recent version in `./home/myapp/apps/myapp/releases.

Once edited you'll need to restart the web server for it to pick up the changes.

Again.. I would highly suggest not doing this unless you have no other option.